# Displaying whole table with optionally empty fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Here is how the database looks like 
[image]

So I would like to display it like

```
Champion name 
name of the column e.g. Q name of the spell - Surging Tides 
the rest of spells for that champion
Next Champion etc.,
```

This is the way I display Champion names right now

```
$champions = $conn->prepare("SELECT *
                             FROM champions 
                             Where Patch_No = ?");
$champions->bind_param('s', $Patch_No);
$champions->execute();
$champions_result = $champions->get_result();

while($row = $champions_result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['Champion'].' '.$row['NumNotNull'].'<br>';    
}
```

I can't really think of an easy way to do this with the least amount of queries possible.

Here is another example how it should look like

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use an HTML table?

Comment: @Barmar what do you mean by HTML table, I just don't know how to properly fetch all of that information to display it like I showed on last imgur

Comment: Doesn't `SELECT *` fetch all the information?

Comment: It doesn't take into consideration names of those columns as far as I'm concerned, I don't know how to loop through PASSIVE Q W E R etc for only existing fields

Comment: `foreach ($row as $column_name => $column)` and then test whether `$column` is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$row` is an associative array, so you can loop through it with `foreach` and test whether the column is empty.

```php
while($row = $champions_result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['Champion'].' '.$row['NumNotNull'].'<br>';
    foreach ($row as $column_name => $column) {
        if ($column_name == 'Champion' || $column_name == 'NumNotNull') {
            continue; // These fields were already displayed above
        }
        if (!empty($column)) {
            echo "$column_name $column<br>";
        }
    } 
}
```